# How to check for nan and empty string

Tags: python, string, nan

I am trying to find all `NaNs` and empty strings (i.e `""`) in a Python list of strings. Please see the following code with 3 options:

```
names=['Pat','Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', '']
for idx,name in enumerate(names):
    if name=='':        #Option 1 
    if pd.isnull(name): #Option 2
    if np.isnan(name):  #Option 3 
        print(idx)
```

- Option 1: This check, `name==""`, doesn't catch `NaN`
- Option 2: This check, `pd.isnull(name)` doesn't catch the empty string
- Option 3: This check, `np.isnan(name)` gives the following error on the strings (e.g "Pat"):

> ----> 6  if np.isnan(name):
> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe*''*

Question: Is there any function/method that can check for empty strings, `NaN`s and does not give an error when it encounters a string?

Comment: Ask yourself: where is your data from, where it has such type errors? Is there a way to fix the input before it even gets here?

Comment: @o11c almost certainly from list-ifying some `pandas` data-structure. You are right, likely, they should filter `NaN`s there...

Comment: @o11c the above is just a simplified example for the question. The actual data is 1.7 million records with 17 columns aggregated from multiple sources to which I don't have access - so it has NaNs, Nones, blanks etc. all over the place.

Answer (score 28):

Just use *both*:

```
>>> names=['Pat','Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', '']
>>> for idx,name in enumerate(names):
...     if name == '' or pd.isnull(name):
...         print(idx)
...
2
4
```

However, realize that:

```
>>> pd.isnull(None)
True
```

So if you want to check *specifically for `NaN`* and not `None`, use `math.isnan` (while guarding against passing non-`float` values to `math.isnan`:

```
>>> import math
>>> for idx,name in enumerate(names):
...     if name == '' or (isinstance(name, float) and  math.isnan(name)):
...         print(idx)
...
2
4
```

Comment: This works and also allows to find real text in columns with actual text strings, NaNs, blanks, None by doing:   if not (name == '' or pd.isnull(name))

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to combine options #1 and #2 and get the result you are looking for:

```
names = ['Pat', 'Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', '']
for idx, name in enumerate(names):
    if not name or pd.isnull(name):
        print(idx)
```